# Building Sequelize JOIN table SQL queries with WHERE table alias

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

Suppose we could use `QueryInterface` provided by sequelize, how can we define the Table Alias in the `Where` clause?

```
            const queryInterface = this.sequelize.getQueryInterface();
            const queryGenerator = queryInterface.queryGenerator as SequelizeQueryGenerator;
            const whereObject = [
                {
                    ['venueid']: {
                        [Op.lt]: 50
                    }
                },
                {
                    ['e.eventid']: { // Attempt to define Table Alias on column
                        [Op.eq]: 100
                    }
                }
            ];
            const sql = queryGenerator.selectQuery(
                [
                    ['venue', 'v'],
                    ['event', 'e']
                ],
                { where: whereObject },
                null
            );
```

Actual output:

```
SELECT * FROM "venue" AS "v", "event" AS "e" WHERE ("v"."venueid" < 50 AND "v"."e.eventid" = 100);
```

Expected output:

```
SELECT * FROM "venue" AS "v", "event" AS "e" WHERE ("v"."venueid" < 50 AND "e"."eventid" = 100);
```

My attempts to make this work is by providing the Alias directly in the `whereObject`

```
               {
                    ['e.eventid']: { // Attempt to define Table Alias on column
                        [Op.eq]: 100
                    }
                }
```

The reason for not using a Model for query is that I'm trying to make this a model-less query service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `where` function, it seems to work.

```js
const whereObject = sequelize.and(
  sequelize.where(Sequelize.col('v.venue_id'), Op.lt, 50),
  sequelize.where(Sequelize.col('e.event_id'), 100)
)
```